# Remove vowels except if it the starting of the word

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the occurrences of the vowels in the string, except if they are the starting of a word. So for example an input like `"The boy is about to win"`   should ouput `Th by is abt t wn`.Here is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def short(s):
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
noVowel= s
toLower = s.lower()
for i in toLower.split():
    if i[0] not in vowels:
        noVowel = noVowel.replace(i, '')        
return noVowel
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. And which part doesn't work?

Comment: Also don't forget "y" which is a vowel, except usually when it starts a word.  The "y" in "boy" is part of a diphthong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> s = "The boy is about to win"
>>> ''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(s) if not (c in 'aeiou' and i>1 and s[i-1].isalpha()))
'Th by is abt t wn'
```

#### How it works:

The key part of the above if the generator:

```
c for i, c in enumerate(s) if not (c in 'aeiou' and i>1 and s[i-1].isalpha())
```

The key part of the generator is the condition:

```
if not (c in 'aeiou' and i>1 and s[i-1].isalpha())
```

This means that all letters in `s` are included unless they are vowels that are not either (a) at the beginning of `s` and hence at the beginning of a word, or (b) preceded by a non-letter which would also mean that they were at the beginning of a word.

#### Rewritten as `for` loop

```
def short(s):
    new = ''
    prior = ''
    for c in s:
        if not (c in 'aeiou' and prior.isalpha()):
            new += c
        prior = c
    return new
```

Comment: this works great! but i haven't much of this? Is there a way to put this into a form including fors and ifs like i did?

Comment: This doesn't handle situations when words starting with vowels are not preceded by spaces: ``s = "The boy is about to win (or draw)"``. That might not be an issue for the OP's data.

Comment: @sm15 I added a looping version.

Comment: @FMc Good point.  I revised the answer to define a word better.

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to use a regular expression that replaces vowels not preceded by a word boundary. Also, you might want to think about some more interesting test cases if your code is supposed to handle arbitrary text with various types of punctuation.

```
import re
s = "The boy is about to win (or draw). Give him a trophy to boost his self-esteem."
rgx = re.compile(r'\B[aeiou]', re.IGNORECASE)
print rgx.sub('', s)  # Th by is abt t wn (or drw). Gv hm a trphy t bst hs slf-estm.
```

Comment: Regex seems to be a very appropriate solution for this type of problem, +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex on the rest of the string (ignoring the first character):

```
import re
s = 'The boy is about to win'
s = s[0] + re.sub(r'[aeiou]', '', s[1:])
print s # Th by s bt t wn
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

re.sub("(?<!\b)[aeiouAEIOU]", '', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Through re.sub.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "The boy is about to win"
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)(?<=\S)[aeiou]', r'', s)
'Th by is abt t wn'
```

`\S` matches any non-space character.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.sub('(?<=\w)[aeiou]','',"The boy is about to win")
'Th by is abt t wn'
```