# How does this for loop and "new = ' ' " work?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
def shortenPlus(s):
    # Yer Code 'Ere Mate!
    # Aye Aye cap'
    new = ''
    prior = ''
    for x in s:
        if not (x in 'aeiou' and prior.isalpha()):
            new += x
        prior = x
    return new

print(shortenPlus("I've information vegetable, animal and mineral"))
```

So here's the code that I found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446136/remove-vowels-except-if-it-the-starting-of-the-word) thread. I am having trouble understanding how the "if not" part of the for loop works, and why we have new and prior statements.

I understand that we take a variable from the string, and if this variable is NOT in 'aeiou', and the prior container does NOT have anything from the alphabet, then you add this variable to new. But if prior is I, and x is v, it doesn't satisfy the prior criteria, and yet it still adds it to new.

This is how I'm understanding it so far. Please let me know what I'm misunderstanding!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! One great way to understand what's happening is to insert `print()` statements to show you what exactly `new` and `prior` are after each iteration. Another thing to do after that is to play with the conditions. Remove one or the other from the `if`, or remove the `not` and see what prints then

Comment: Also: [How to step through python code to debug issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/how-to-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)

Comment: Useful relations (deMorgans): (1) not A and not B == not (A or B) ............(2) not A or not B == not (A and B). Rewrite your code using those, to see if it's more understandable.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I would recommend learning more Python, and about programming in general. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a slight logical misunderstanding. The code specifies `NOT (A AND B)`; this is equivalent to `NOT A OR NOT B`. In other words:

> if this variable is NOT in 'aeiou', OR the prior container does NOT have anything from the alphabet, then you add this variable to new

So, continuing your hypothetical, if `prior` is `I`, and `x` is `v`, then:

- `x in 'aeiou'` is false
- `prior.isalpha()` is true

therefore:

- `x in 'aeiou' and prior.isalpha()` is false

therefore:

- `not(x in 'aeiou' and prior.isalpha())` is true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand

`if not(x in 'aeiou' and prior.isalpha()): ...`

to

```
inner = x in 'aeiou' and prior.isalpha()
if not inner:
    ...
```

for clarity. Now, `inner` will be True if and only if both conditions are true:

- `x` is a vowel
- The previous character is a letter

If *either* of those is not true, then `inner` will be False. So, the original test:

`not(x in 'aeiou' and prior.isalpha())`

negates that, and will be *False* if both of those conditions are met. If either (or both!) are not met, then it will be *True*, and the if-statement will be evaluated. Therefore, the if-statement will be evaluated if:

- `x` is *not* a value
- and/or the previous character is *not* a letter.

Answer (score 1):

> I am having trouble understanding [...] why we have new and prior statements.

`new` and `prior` are variables, not statements.  The code is using `new` to build up a new string, and `prior` to store the character from the previous iteration of the for-loop.

> if this variable is NOT in 'aeiou', and the prior container does NOT have anything from the alphabet

Your understanding of the logic isn't quite right.  The `new += x` line is executed if **both** `x in 'aeiou'` AND `prior.isalpha()` evaluate to false -- which (per [De Morgan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra)) is equivalent to saying, the `new += x` line is executed if **either** `x not in 'aeiou'` **or**  `prior.isalpha()==False` (or both).

So, the code will add a character to the string as long as either it's not a vowel, **or** the previous character was not a letter, or both.

Answer (score 0):

'new' there is the new string which is generated by the for.

'prior' serves to make the condition, which depends on the previous character in the original string it goes thru.

As a comment mentions, adding prints to every step is a good way to see what's going on.